# getting scientific notation when converting from string to blob to save to csv

Tags: apex, string, blob

I have a long string that I want to save to CSV. I use the following code to convert the string to blob and save as a file:

```
Attachment newFile = new Attachment();
newFile.Name = getReportFileName();
newFile.Body = Blob.valueOf(csvContent);
```

However, when I open the csv, I see some numbers are formatted like 1.00E+01 instead of 10. I thought this is an Excel issue and opened the raw file in another editor (Notepad++) and still see the same format, which makes me think it is an issue with the generated file and not Excel. Obviously, I could not find anything related in the [Blob Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm) documentation and when I debug the values in the code before saving to file, the numbers are shown correctly. The problematic values are calculated with this code

`String.ValueOf(Math.abs(myRecord.customNumericField__c.stripTrailingZeros()))`

What can be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible solutions. You can turn the decimal (i'm guessing that) to a plain string with the toPlainString() method.

> Returns the String value of this Decimal, without using scientific
>   notation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_toPlainString

Or you can tell excel to treat the column as a numeric value. It should just convert it to normal numbers for you.